# Selenium Webdriver - Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have  a Selenium Webdriver JUnit Java test and I am unable to use locators successfully within a Drupal 8 table (which also has styling). In Firefox I can use Firepath and Xpath checker to determine and check the xpath OK. However when I run the JUnit 4 test it is unable to be located. What was interesting is that the first time I ran this test it worked ok, however many attempts afterwards and it will not run.

I have used xpath etc successfully for many other tests within this web site, but for some reason I cannot get this to work.

Actually the unable to locate element message is for the next command;

```
driver.findElement(By.id("edit-application-status-1")).click();
```

however I know it is failing on the previous command (as below) because it never clicks to get to this page.

Failing code;

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block-ua-theme-content']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a")).click();
```

also tried;

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/application-19']")).click();
```

I have tried changing to `cssSelector` with explict wait as below

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[href='/application-19']")));`

scroll into view as below;

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/application-19']"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element1);
```

Comment: Share website URL or html code

Comment: And please share the code of WebDriver initialization to see what  implementation you are using

Answer (score 0):

Handling Web table could be tricky so it's better to traverse all the elements of WebTable one by one ; then check if your element has been found and then trigger your action:

```
List<WebElement> tableElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block-ua-theme-content']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td"));


        for(WebElement item : tableElements){

        System.out.println("item text : " + item.getText());

            if(item.getText().equals("Text of your  <a> tag")){

                 WebElement newItem =  item.findElement(By.tagName("a"));

                newItem.click();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it also didn't work?List<WebElement> tableElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block-ua-theme-content']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]"));

         for(WebElement item : tableElements){

             if(item.getText().equals("Abhimanyujeet")){

                 WebElement newItem =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("/a"));

                 newItem.click();

             }

Comment: Unable to locate element. But this is for the next command. It seems to be skipping over this code without clicking on the item.

Comment: I've updated the code; please run this and share your output (along with error trace)

Comment: Before
item text : Singh Abhimanyujeet a1706988 D0000130 Bachelor of Arts (Advanced) 10 April 2017 at 09:49 Submitted 18 Sep 1997 Male Submitted on 11 Apr 2017
After

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #edit\-application\-status\-1

Comment: "Singh" is a link in the first column. "Abhimanyujeet" is a link in the second column of this row.

Comment: @Steve_Harlington: I've updated my code; it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Click on first item in list tr[1]
        System.out.println("Before");
        List<WebElement> tableElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//[@id='block-ua-theme-content']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]"));

        for(WebElement item : tableElements){

            if(item.getText().equals("Abhimanyujeet")){

                WebElement newItem =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("/a"));
                System.out.println("tableElements" + tableElements);
                System.out.println("item" + item);

                newItem.click();

            }
        }
        System.out.println("After");

        driver.findElement(By.id("edit-application-status-1")).click();
```

Console;

Before

```
tableElements[EyesRemoteWebElement:[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (acecd5e9-    e491-4afd-9f78-82351e50b9e4)] -> xpath: .//*[@id='block-ua-theme-content']    /div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]]]

itemEyesRemoteWebElement:[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (acecd5e9-e491-4afd- 9f78-82351e50b9e4)] -> xpath: .//*[@id='block-ua-theme-content']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]]
```

After

Trace;

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #edit\-application\-status\-1
```

Comment: So error is for `"edit-application-status-1"` try using `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#edit-application-status-1")).click();`

Comment: The error reported is "edit-application-status-1"; however this is not the real problem. This element is on the next page. The problem is that this element; driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/application-18']")).click(); is never clicked so it seems to skip over this and try and click "edit-application-status-1" which of course will fail be because we are not on that page yet.

Comment: I am seeing this as a general problem. Where it seems Selenium thinks it has clicked on an item so moves to the next line of code where it fails, because the previous item has not been clicked on meaning the next element is of course not present.

Comment: @Test
 public void i_aa_ITR_Assessor() throws Exception {
          
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

   driver = eyes.open(driver, "AatA_5", "ITR Assessor", new RectangleSize(1024, 700));
   
   driver.get(baseUrl + "/");